# How to share screenshot with URL to App?

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, share

I need help here please. The code below works perfect, but i want to add some message and a URL when the screenshot is shared from the android App to Facebook.
Currently the code below does only take a screenshot and share it, but i want to be shared with an URL and/or message.

```
 //share button
        btn_share = new Instance(new Sprite(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Share), (int) this.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.share), secondaryFont, this.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_share_btn)), 0, 0, this, false);
        btn_share.y = ScreenHeight() / 2 + ScreenWidth() / 4 + btn_share.getHeight() / 2;
        btn_share.x = ScreenWidth() / 2 - btn_share.getWidth() / 2;

//share screenshot
                btn_share.unHighlight();
                if (btn_share.isTouched(event)) {
                    share();
                    if (sound_button != 0 && !sound_muted)
                        sp.play(sound_button, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                }

//share screenshot
    public void share() {
        //share
        Share sharer = new Share();
        screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setBitmap(screenshot);
        int temp_state = state;
        state = GAMEPLAY;
        Draw(canvas);
        state = temp_state;
        sharer.share_screenshot(this, screenshot);

    }`



`
```

Comment: if you are looking for the code to share content to FB check this link   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: what message exactly? you do know that prefiling a message is not allowed, right? just to be sure.

Comment: I want to add the url of the play store app with the shared screenshot by default

Comment: You are not allowed to add anything to the user message. If you want this, then you need to let them share the URL to your app, and use the image as the thumbnail image for that URL.